# u-boot disable DHCP requests with setenv

Tags: ip, dhcp, u-boot

I am trying to disable the DHCP requests after the Kernel was loaded. Using *`freescale imx25 dev-board`* in standard config. In `u-boot`, I find two lines `ip=dhcp`:

```
MX25 U-Boot > pri
bootdelay=3
baudrate=115200
loadaddr=0x80800000
netdev=eth0
ethprime=smc911x-0
uboot=u-boot.bin
uboot_addr=0xa0000000
kernel=uImage
bootargs_base=setenv bootargs console=ttymxc0,115200
bootargs_nfs=setenv bootargs $(bootargs) root=/dev/nfs ip=dhcp nfsroot=$(serverip):$(nfsrootfs),v3,tcp
bootcmd_net=run bootargs_base bootargs_nfs; tftpboot ${loadaddr} ${kernel}; bootm
load_uboot=tftpboot ${loadaddr} ${uboot}
ethact=smc911x-0
bootargs_nand=setenv bootargs ${bootargs} root=/dev/mtdblock2 ip=dhcp rootfstype=jffs2
bootcmd_nand=run bootargs_base bootargs_nand; nand read ${loadaddr} 0x100000 0x1d2000;bootm
bootcmd=run bootcmd_nand
serverip=192.168.0.5
ipaddr=192.168.0.100
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
stderr=serial
```

If I do:

```
set bootargs_nand=setenv bootargs ${bootargs} root=/dev/mtdblock2 ip=192.168.0.100 rootfstype=jffs2
```

It does not work and my boot environment seems to be completely damaged.

How can I assign a fixed IP address without changing other parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Your command:

```
set bootargs_nand=setenv bootargs ${bootargs} root=/dev/mtdblock2
      ip=192.168.0.100 rootfstype=jffs2
```

will not work as it is.

It should at least be:

```
setenv bootargs_nand 'setenv bootargs ${bootargs} root=/dev/mtdblock2
       ip=192.168.0.100 rootfstype=jffs2'
```

without an `=` sign, and using single quotes to prevent expansion of `${bootargs}` until the `bootargs_nand` command is actually run.

To make the IP setting more flexible, you should also specify `ip=${ipaddr}` within that command rather than explicitly using the actual address. The Uboot environment value will be substituted.

This answer is preliminary until these defects have been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it with ip additional params:

```
setenv netargs 'setenv bootargs console=${console} root=/dev/nfs ip=${ipaddr}:::::eth0:off rw nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootfs},v3,tcp'
```

See kernel/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt:

```
ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:
   <dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>:<ntp0-ip>
```